# Finding the Fourier coefficints with NFourierCoefficient or FourierCoefficient?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would like to calculate the Fourier coefficients of the function and then plot them on the fourier transform of it, as well as on the Fourier series of it.

This is what I do:

```
   y[x_] := Piecewise[{{2, -2 < x < -1}, {1, -1 < x < 0}, {2, 0 < x < 1}, {3, 1 < x < 2}}]
    Y[t_] := y[u 2/Pi]
    Plot[Y[u], {u, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> None]
```

Then  I generate the FourierSeries:

```
   FourierSeries[Y[u], u, 20]
p0=Plot[%, {u, -Pi, Pi}]
```

Then I generate the Fourier Transform

```
        F[\[Omega]_] := FourierTransform[Y[u], u, \[Omega]]
   p1= Plot[Evaluate[Re[F[\[Omega]]]], {\[Omega], -Pi, Pi}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "F_(\[Omega])"}]
```

and finally, I wanted to calculate the coefficients:

```
 NFourierCoefficient[Y[u], u, 20]
```

and

```
FourierCoefficient[Y[u], u, 20]
```

However they give nothing.

How can I find these coefficients and plot them on the plots p0 and p1?

Thanks

Comment: "FourierCoefficient" gives only 1 coefficient. The syntax for all 20  is `FourierCoefficient[f[x], x, #] & /@ Range[0, 20]`

Comment: Thanks Daniel!!

Comment: @Daniel Huber I am trying to prove that Document I sent you. But the plot of the coefficients is a plot in the complex plane, and has no apparent similarities to the Fourier Transform!

Comment: The plot is a plot of the real part of the Fourier transform.

Comment: Yes, that is here too. Do you mean I should plot only the real part of the coefficients?

Comment: The paper says real part of coefficient and real part of Fourier transform.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to plot the real part of those coefficients then.